# how to make circle view?

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to make a circle view  in android

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
Solution:-

    
    
   class CircleView : View {
        private var paint: Paint? = null
        private var bgpaint: Paint? = null
        private var drawable: Drawable? = null
        private var text1: Paint? = null
        private var rect: RectF? = null
        private var negativeValue = 50f
        private var positiveValue = 50f
    
     }
```